# Stop links from executing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I can stop normal inks from working with this:

```
  $('#container a').click(function(event) {
    return false;
  });
```

However my site has existing javascript that fires when a link is clicked. The code above doenst stop these from firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may unbind click and stopPropagation

```
$('#container a').unbind('click').click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   //event.preventDefault();
   return false;
 });
```

Comment: will `preventDefault` remove other bound event handlers?

Comment: Should there be a ; after the () ?

Answer (score 0):

if the other click events are bound with jquery, as long as this event is bound after those you should be able to do:

```
$('#container a').off('click').on('click', function(event) {
  return false;
});
```

the `.off` will remove previously bound click event before binding the new 
one

(`off` is `unbind` for events added with `on`)

Answer (score 0):

You can `unbind` event from selected elements http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

```
$('#container a').unbind("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) and [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) it removes event handlers.

> Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

```
$('#container a').off('click').on('click', function(event) {
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an aside, but this can also be done with CSS

```
pointer-events: none
```